# VScode prettier twig and javascript problem

Tags: visual-studio-code, twig, prettier

VSCode and prettier. Twig plus included javascript.

[before prettier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvcRG.png)

[after prettier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcW4o.png)

Twig is like html file. VS code json setting:

```
  "files.associations": {
    "*.twig": "twig"
  },
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "twig": "html"
  },
```

How setup prettier to better format script?

Comment: Still need a solution for this too